# Jquery Ajax Servlet simple calculator

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I would like to create a simple calculator using jquery ajax servlet.There will be two textboxes for numbers  and then the dropdown list to select the operator and an another textbox for result and main thing is that there should not be any submit button. Its like, as soon as user enter numbers to the two textboxes and select an operator, mean while the result should display in result textbox.  I hope you all got my question. Please please help me..

Thanks

Comment: you only need javascript for this, no ajax is required

Comment: You only need `ajax` if you need call some server side `functions` such as `database` calls. In computing `numbers` you just need some input and some logic....

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="yourid">
<option value="Value 1">+</option>
<option value="Value 2">-</option>
</select>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$('#yourid').change(function() {
  $.ajax({url: "calculate?text1="val1"&text1="val2"&op="+";

                        error: function() {
                            alert("Some Error is there..");
                        },
                        success: function(result) {

                            alert(result);
                            //$("#div1").html(result);
                        }});

});
</script>
```

Comment: hey itz an example u can do on change event and pass your value using get method using question mark

Comment: Hi Mayur,
  Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629277/jquery-ajax-servlet-simple-calculator